# Am I obligated to disclose to my boss that somebody else recommended me to our competitor?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I work in a small town with two newspapers. A "friend" took it upon herself to recommend me for a job at the paper I do not work at. Now I am in a position of deciding whether to tell my boss about this. This is a very small town and it is only a matter of time before she hears some version of it. I am in an uncomfortable position here. Should I tell my boss? And I am concerned if I do my friend will be offended. While I did not ask her to do this nor did I express any desire to leave my current situation, I don't think she meant any harm...???

Comment: Why would you need to tell your boss you got recommended for a position?  If you are not interested and they contact you just tell them you are not interested.

Comment: Does the other paper have your resume, or just your name?  Are you considering a job with the other paper?  What do you expect your boss to hear, and how might that affect your relationship and current job?

Comment: Ask on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ how to talk to your friend. If you have no interest in moving now, you might have in future - and she might have messed it up for you, depending on what she said. For instance, if she told them that you were keen to join the other paper and you "turn it down" ...

Answer (score 2):

> Should I tell my boss?

Unless your friend is going to pay your bills, you need to worry about your job *first*.  **If** your confident (*really confident*) your boss will find out no matter what, simply **tell them the truth**, and tell them before they hear it via the rumor mill.

If they hear about it elsewhere *first*, you will have lost some credibility.

> And I am concerned if I do my friend will be offended.

This is *secondary* to keeping your job.  Once you tell your boss, explain to your friend that you felt like you had to tell your boss in order to maintain a good relationship.  Your friend *should* be fine with this.